# How Can I Add Column Resizing to Lightning Design System Data Table?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning, lightning-design-system

I am working to build a Lightning Design System data table. I will have several columns that will push the width of the table body beyond a normal screen width. Therefore, I want to add column resizing to the table. I see that the LDS guide gives the CSS classes needed to display the resize bar, but not the interactive code via Javascript to execute the resize. I was unsure how to achieve this.

I did not know if there is an OOTB way to do this via LDS or if custom Javascript would be needed?

The LDS guide section I am referencing can be found [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#flavor-advanced).

Answer (score 4):

There is no out of the box way to do it in LDS. This has been discussed [here](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/issues/167) as well.

There are several JS plugins which can help you achieve this though. A popular one is [colResizable](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#samples)

Sample code

```
$("#sample").colResizable({
        liveDrag:true
});
```

You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156182/resizable-table-columns-with-jquery) thread which lists multiple approaches and pick one based on our use cases (e.g. drag)